# "I do not have any time to lose" vs "I do not have time to lose"

Tags: meaning

I saw these two sentences reading books or articles.
Is there a difference of meaning between them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning.  Both sentences express the negation of time.

However, the use of any in the former makes the negation emphatic.  The sentence means that you don't have the smallest amount of time to lose/you don't have time at all to lose.